# how to prevent disassociated elastic ip from getting automatically reassigned to the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-ip

I'm working on 2 single instance EB apps (app1, app2 with ec2_1, ec2_2 instances) that have elastic ips associated with them (EIP_1, EIP_2). They are built on a non-default VPC with one network interface each. I'm trying to associate the EIP of ec2_1 to ec2_2.

Although I was able to successfully disassociate EIP_1 from ec2_1, disassociate EIP_2 from ec2_2 and reassign EIP_1 to ec2_2, the changes stay only momentarily. Within a few seconds, it all goes back to EIP_1 -> ec2_1; EIP_2 -> ec2_2 assignment. I'm not sure how or why this is happening.

How can I prevent this from happening and stay with my EIP_1 assignment to ec2_2?

Comment: I don't know of any AWS feature that would cause this to happen. It sounds like another process is making an API call to disassociate and associate the IP addresses back.

Comment: EB uses CloudFormation to set up EIPs for single instance EB apps. Looks like that modifies it.